# trying to get jquery image zoom plugin to work

Tags: jquery, image, zooming

this is the plugin i am trying to work
http://andreaslagerkvist.com/jquery/image-zoom/

no matter what i do when i click the a tag nothing happens
and i get no errors as well...
this is my html i created for testing purposes

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.imageZoom.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.imageZoom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("div.jquery-image-zoom").imageZoom();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="jquery-image-zoom">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://exscale.se/__files/3d/bloodcells.jpg">Bloodcells</a></li>
<li><a href="http://exscale.se/__files/3d/x-wing.jpg">X-Wing</a></li>
<li><a href="http://exscale.se/__files/3d/weve-moved.jpg">We've moved</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://exscale.se/__files/3d/lamp-and-mates/lamp-and-mates-01.jpg">
<img src="http://exscale.se/__files/3d/lamp-and-mates/lamp-and-mates-01_small.jpg" alt="Lamp and Mates" /></a></li>
<li><a href="http://exscale.se/__files/3d/stugan-winter.jpg">
<img src="http://exscale.se/__files/3d/stugan-winter_small.jpg" alt="The Cottage - Winter      time" /></a></li>
<li><a href="http://exscale.se/__files/3d/ps2.jpg">
<img src="http://exscale.se/__files/3d/ps2_small.jpg" alt="PS2" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

any chance someone could try and  get a working copy of that online so i could compare with my own and finally realize what did i do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I notice is you use an ID tag but you don't select an ID.  You selected a class.  Also, I you might want to do this when the `document` is `ready`.

Correct selector:

```
$('document').ready( function() {
    $("div#jquery-image-zoom").imageZoom();
});
```

Comment: whoooa i think it did the trick, care to explain to a newbie like me? im new to jquery

Comment: Here's a good reference:
http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

The rest is understanding of CSS and javascript.   The ready runs when the page is finished rendering the html.  If you do not, the function called is not going to run.  And you must know the difference between "." and "#".   I would just check out basic examples.  The references on the web have better examples and probably in a way you'd understand best.